# nvl multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I select from two subqueries s1 and s2. If the value for a column in s2 is null can I use nvl to retrieve a column in s1?

```
select
    s1.name_last
    nvl(s2.proj_mgr, s1.func_mgr)
from
    (...) s1
    left outer join
    (...) s2
on
    s1.empid = s2.owner_id
;
```

Comment: Did you try it? Look ok too me.

Comment: Yup!  Also, depending on how complex `(...)` is, you may want to consider using `with`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use `coalesce()` instead.  It has two advantages.  First, it is ANSI standard and so is available in multiple databases.  Second, it can take multiple arguments:

```
select s1.name_last, coalesce(s2.proj_mgr, s1.func_mgr)
from (...) s1 left outer join
     (...) s2
     on s1.empid = s2.owner_id
;
```

Comment: Another advantage of `coalesce()` over `nvl()` is that `nvl()` evaluates both arguments before deciding whether the first is null or not, while `coalesce()` only evaluates subsequent arguments if the prior argument is indeed null. Handy when the selected argument is another nested select statement.

Comment: @Wolf . . . That is interesting.  In SQL Server, a *disadvantage* of `coalesce()` is that it evaluates the first argument twice.  Alas, differences among databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was looking for a source to cite, but for anyone who is curious here is a quick example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/8184).